# Retry using Retrofit2 + RxJava + Jackson for 202 Status Code

Tags: android, jackson, rx-java, retrofit2

I have an API which returns 200, 202, 4xx based on different scenarios. When I get a 202, I am supposed to make the same API until I get a 200 or 4xx. I tried using doOnErrorNext, onError, onNext. I was not able to crack the problem

```
Observable<MyPOJO> makeAPI();

Observable<MyPOJO> makeAPIImpl(){

makeAPI().doOnErrorNext(/*how to I access the error code here*/);
makeAPI().doOnNext(/*given that 202 is a success code, I expected it to come here, but it goes to Error because of JSON Mapping*/);

}
```

doOnErrorNext -> I was able to make the API call again but then it would happen for all the error scenarios which I dont want

I have checked multiple answers regarding this, but nobody has solved this combination specifically and am unable to incorporate other answers to my use case.

Comment: well, 202 is success code so retrofit will try to parse it and probably in your case parsing failed with Exception. does the server returns 202 where response is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use OkHttp and use an interceptor to retry your request, something along these lines (this is from one of my apps in Kotlin, but it should give you the idea):

```
inner class ExpiredSessionInterceptor : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        if (response.code() == 202) {
            val newRequest = request.newBuilder().build()
            return chain.proceed(newRequest)
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
val httpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
httpClientBuilder.addInterceptor(ExpiredSessionInterceptor())

val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(SERVER_ENDPOINT_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))            
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
        .client(httpClientBuilder.build())
        .build()
```

Comment: Okay, I will check this out. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it. It worked well for the first time. But it did not hit the 2nd time onwards. Is there anything that you think is causing this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I adapted this from my code where I retry once when I get a specific response from the server I talk to. You may need to step into the OkHttp code to understand why it only works once. You may need to create a new request, but without a means to reproduce is hard to say what could be the issue.